# VB equivalent to c# new byte[0]

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm trying to convert some C# to VB.  Calling this method:

```
public static void WriteLineA(Stream Stream, byte[] Line);
```

The C# call looks like this:

```
SBASUtils.__Global.WriteLineA(messageStream, new byte[0]);
```

All the C# > VB converters convert the byte to this:

```
New Byte(-1) {}
```

Compiler doesn't like that.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanx!

Comment: why would you be writing out an empty byte array in the first place?

Comment: Well, I assume the WriteLineA appends CRLF to end of the empty byte array.  Probabaly just their way to add an extra CRLF to the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SBASUtils.__Global.WriteLineA(messageStream, New Byte() {})
```

That will create a new byte array automatically sized to the number of elements between the curly brackets.  Since there are no items between the brackets, it will create it as an empty (zero items) array.